# Login Example in Android using POST method using REST API

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am working on my First Android application where we have our own REST API, url will be like. "www.abc.com/abc/def/" . For login activity i need to do httppost by passing 3 parameters as identifier, email and password. Then after getting the http response, i need to show the dialogbox whether Invalid Credentials or Switch to another activity.

Can someone please show me sample code for how to do this?

Comment: There are examples all over the internet, for example: http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html or search StackOverflow of course: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714817/send-login-with-post-with-android.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easy way to complete this task is to using a library, if your familiar with libraries. I recommend [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) because it's small and easy to work with. Add the library and add the following snippet to the method of your choice.

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
.load("http://www.example.com/abc/def/")
.setBodyParameter("identifier", "foo")
.setBodyParameter("email", "foo@foo.com")
.setBodyParameter("password", "p@ssw0rd")
.asString()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
        // Result
    }
});
```

Notice! If you want to make network calls you must add the following permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` outside the `<application>` tag if you're not aware of that.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

To check the response for successful login, or failure you can add the following snippet inside the `onComplete`-method (where the `// Result` is).:

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);    // Converts the string "result" to a JSONObject
        String json_result = json.getString("result"); // Get the string "result" inside the Json-object
        if (json_result.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){ // Checks if the "result"-string is equals to "ok"
            // Result is "OK"
            int customer_id = json.getInt("customer_id"); // Get the int customer_id
            String customer_email = json.getString("customer_email"); // I don't need to explain this one, right?
        } else {
            // Result is NOT "OK"
            String error = json.getString("error");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // This will show the user what went wrong with a toast
            Intent to_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class); // New intent to MainActivity
            startActivity(to_main); // Starts MainActivity
            finish(); // Add this to prevent the user to go back to this activity when pressing the back button after we've opened MainActivity
        }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        // This method will run if something goes wrong with the json, like a typo to the json-key or a broken JSON.
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Why do we need a try & catch, well first of all we are forced to and on the other hand, it will prevent the application to crash if something goes wrong with the JSON-parsing.

Comment: My JSON returns Response like { "result": "ok", "customer_id": 1, "customer_email": "example@eg.com" ,"error":" "}

on failure it returns { "result": "error", "error": "invalid credentials"}

can you please show me snippet how to get this response and do particular action like redirect to mainactivity on success.?

Comment: @Veer3383 There you go :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. in my previous implementation i used to get JSON exception. Your solution solves that problem. now i get "invalid identifier" as an error when i click on Sign in... guess thats problem with my api key

Comment: You're welcome @Veer3383, actually why you might get that error was due to using `getString` when you was supposed to use `getInt`? It's just a hunch

Comment: identifier is some guid so that only i can make api calls. which has already set static by the one who has created API. I need to pass that same identifier while using POST to authenticate myself. I am not returning it back. using getInt for customer_id and get String for email shall be perfectly fine. i have added "Ion.with(getApplicationContext()) snippet you showed" to my button onClickListener. It makes api call right?

Comment: Yeah, it sends an POST :)

Answer (score 4):

this is how you can handle this from scratch, in your login Activity use this block of code and if you are using POST method you will modify a little bit  because I used a GET Method to check credidentials, **LoginHandler extends AsyncTask because it is not allowed to make Network Operations on main Thread**...

```
private class  LoginHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String URL = "url to get from ";

            JSONObject jsonReader=null;


            try {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                        responseString = out.toString();
                        jsonReader=new JSONObject(responseString);
                    } else {
                        // Closes the connection.
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Handle problems..
                    String er=e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle problems..
                    String er=e.getMessage();
                }

                // Show response on activity

                if (!jsonReader.get("UserName").toString().equals("")) {
                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("LoginInfos", 0);
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();

                    editor.putString("email", jsonReader.getString("EmailAddress"));
                    editor.putString("username", jsonReader.getString("UserName"));
                    editor.putString("userid", jsonReader.getString("UserId"));
                    editor.putString("realname", jsonReader.getString("RealName"));
                    editor.putString("realsurname", jsonReader.getString("RealSurname"));
                    editor.putString("userprofileimage", jsonReader.getString("UserProfileImage"));




                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
                    // get current date time with Date()
                    Date date = new Date();

                    editor.putString("LastLogin",
                            dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
                    editor.commit();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

            return false;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if (result) {
                pdialog.dismiss();
                Intent userMainActivityIntent = new Intent(
                         getApplicationContext(), MainUserActivity.class);
                startActivity(userMainActivityIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                pdialog.dismiss();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Login Error")
                .setMessage("Email or password is wrong.").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            } ).show();

            }




            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the below code on login button onclick

```
 binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (binding.emailInput.getText() == null) {
                binding.emailContainer.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.email_username_empty));
            } else if (binding.emailInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                binding.emailContainer.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.email_username_empty));
            } else if (binding.passwordInput.getText() == null) {
                binding.passwordContainer.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.password_empty));
            } else if (binding.passwordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                binding.passwordContainer.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.password_empty));
            } else {
                callLogIn(binding.emailInput.getText().toString(), binding.passwordInput.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

2. Call below method in login button

```
 private void callLogIn(String email, String password) {
        if (AppUtil.isInternetAvailable(Login.this)) {
            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(binding.emailInput.getText()).matches())
                    jsonObject.put("email", email);
                else
                    jsonObject.put("username", email);
                jsonObject.put("password", password);
                jsonObject.put("device", getResources().getString(R.string.android));
                jsonObject.put("fcm_id", Prefs.getPrefInstance().getValue(Login.this, Const.FCM_ID, ""));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String params = jsonObject.toString();
            final RequestBody user_logging_in = RequestBody.create(params, MediaType.parse("application/json"));
            APIUtils.getAPIService().user_login(user_logging_in).enqueue(new Callback<LoginUserResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LoginUserResponse> call, @NonNull Response<LoginUserResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getStatus() != null && response.body().getStatus().equals(200)) {
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.LOGIN_ACCESS, getString(R.string.logged_in));
                            if (binding.rememberMe.isChecked()) {
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.PASSWORD, password);
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.USER_NAME_EMAIL_CHECKED, email);
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.KEEP_USER_LOGGED_IN, "1");
                            } else {
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.PASSWORD, "");
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.USER_NAME_EMAIL_CHECKED, "");
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.KEEP_USER_LOGGED_IN, "0");
                            }
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.EMAIL, response.body().getData().get(0).getEmail());
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.USER_ID, response.body().getData().get(0).getUserId());
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.USER_NAME, response.body().getData().get(0).getUsername());
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.PHONE_NUMBER, response.body().getData().get(0).getPhone());
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.USER_FULL_NAME, response.body().getData().get(0).getName());
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.TOKEN, response.body().getToken());
                            if (response.body().getData().get(0).getImage() != null && !response.body().getData().get(0).getImage().isEmpty())
                                Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(Login.this, Const.PROFILE_IMAGE, response.body().getData().get(0).getImage());

                            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            AppUtil.show_Snackbar(Login.this, binding.mainContainer, response.body().getMessage(), true);
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, HomeScreen.class));
                        } else {
                            binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(Login.this, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setView(dialog_view)
                                    .show();

                            if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                                dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                            ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText(response.body().getMessage());
                            (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                            dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(Login.this, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setView(dialog_view)
                                .show();

                        if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                            dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                        ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText("Something went wrong! Please try again.");
                        (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                        dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<LoginUserResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(Login.this, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setView(dialog_view)
                            .show();

                    if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                    ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText("Something went wrong! Please try again.");
                    (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
                    dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            View dialog_view = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this).inflate(AppUtil.setLanguage(Login.this, R.layout.simple_dialog_text_button), null);
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setView(dialog_view)
                    .show();

            if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
                dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

            ((TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));
            (dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((Button) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel)).setText("OK");
            dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
        }
    }
```