# Android Simple POST and GET requests to an API url

Tags: android, json, api, post, get

I'm very new in the topic that the title describes, and I'm bit lost, so I'd like some guidance. Basically, first I'd like to make a POST request to a URL from an API. Then check that if the user managed to login and grab the bearer token as a response. Finally, I'd like to make a GET request (including the bearer token I got earlier) in order to receive some other data (there are many products there with their titles, image urls, etc). I guess in both cases I will have to receive a kind of a JSON. I've checked a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549315/login-example-in-android-using-post-method-using-rest-api) and I think it will probably do the trick to me for the Login. However, will this also work for the GET request for the other data afterwards?

Finally, when I get a JSON with the data (from the GET request), any idea how to convert some parts of the JSON to string arrays? (for example to get the product titles, image urls from it) so I want those URLs in a string array and in another string array to similarly store their titles etc.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Koush/Ion example**

In the gradle.build add:

```
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0'
```

And this is an example of what you would use in your Activity class (tested):

```
private void post() {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        // add whatever variables you need
        json.addProperty( "username", "user" );
        json.addProperty( "password", "password" );

        Ion.with( this )
                .load("https://example.com/rest/credentials")
                .setJsonObjectBody( json )
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        // let's suppose the result looks like this: { "result": { "token": "AFDfz553#FF0015" } }
                        String token = result.getAsJsonObject( "result" ).get( "token" ).getAsString();
                        get( token );
                    }
                });
    }

    private void get( String token ) {
        Ion.with( this )
                .load("https://example.com/rest/api/product")
                .addQuery( "token", token )
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        // do stuff with the result or error, for example : {"prod_title" : "The Tittle", "imageUrl" : "blabla"}
                        String title = result.get( "prod_title" ).getAsString();
                        String imgSrc = result.get( "imageUrl" ).getAsString();
                        //etc... or add all values to a List
                        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                        for ( String k : result.keySet() ) {
                            values.add( result.get( k ).getAsString() );
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

The `addQuery` part in the `Get` method adds the token as a parameter to the loaded url. In the example above the url `https://example.com/rest/api/product` becomes `https://example.com/rest/api/product?token=tokenValue`

Comment: The results from the 2nd request (GET) are like [ {"prod_title" : "The Tittle", "imageUrl" : "https://www.blabla...."} etc. ]

Comment: You would probably want to pull those values by their names: receivedJson.getString("prod_title"); etc.

Comment: you mean with a loop?

Comment: basically what I wanna achieve is first use a username and a password that the user will enter, then make a POST request to get a bearer token (if credentials are valid) and then use this bearer token to make a GET request and get the json with the product info. any idea if I can do it with the link I posted or u got any other guidance? thanks.

Comment: You definitely can, I changed my answer to comply with the link you placed.