# Android ION post request failing

Tags: android, api, post, request, android-ion

I've tried to make a POST request using ION as showcased [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549315/login-example-in-android-using-post-method-using-rest-api) but I'm getting the following errors.

```
2020-11-30 14:08:37.353 8610-8651/com.example.test_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ion-ion
Process: com.example.test_app, PID: 8610
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.write(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:492)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handleHandshakeStatus(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:378)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handshake(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:182)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.tryHandshake(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:89)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware$2.onConnectCompleted(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:106)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSocketMiddleware.lambda$getSocket$3$AsyncSocketMiddleware(AsyncSocketMiddleware.java:217)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$AsyncSocketMiddleware$glazjOxu-iNIRY4N890Wl1ngyGo.onCompleted(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$setCallback$0(SimpleFuture.java:212)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$h_gK5Y1XHZI1H8JTE2xOg4dXbp8.onCompleted(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:191)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:174)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$VNAuWcttAhMr3VsWCERbmWE6yR0.success(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$success$4(SimpleFuture.java:279)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$DxIsaj7NQi76eWgOKS4iviWPLV0.onCompleted(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:191)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:178)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$cBC5du-82c5EcL72rP5wNK7Y2Y4.onConnectCompleted(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:896)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:717)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:46)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$11.run(AsyncServer.java:671)
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was that this library doesn't seem to work with Gradle versions newer than 4.0.1.