# How can I connect to my Amazon EC2 server with android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-post, server

I am new to amazon EC2 web server. My client has given the URL like this  http://ec2-00-00-000-000.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000. I want to use this url for fetching data from server or sending data to the server.

For example i have a login module. I want to sent username and password through this url over internet. How can i do this? Anyone can provide me the code. It will be helpful for me

thanks in advance.

Comment: do u have a web application running behind that server?

Comment: no i dont have web application. Once i sent user name and password in post method. I will get response is in the format of json

Comment: and how will you get that response without a web application running in the server side?

Comment: sorry, web application is there.

Comment: then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714817/send-login-with-post-with-android